# Excel VBA inputbox confirmation causes do loop to find only the first value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following Excel VBA code to allow users to perform a final manual inspection of data. If the data are not acceptable, I want to delete the record; if the data are acceptable, I want to keep the record. Following user input and execution of code, I want to move on to the next row marked "Potential False Detection."

A previous macro highlights potential false values in yellow and marks them as "Potential False Detection" in column Y. The input box code is supposed to either delete false rows or update the fill color, then move on to the next "Potential False Detection", but doesn't loop correctly; instead it just seems to select whatever cell was last selected. When I delete the inputbox code and replace it with code that just highlights the cell containing "Potential False Detection", the script runs fine.

Here is the flawed code:

```
        Sub deleteFalseManualInspection()
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim datatoFind
        Dim FirstAddress As String
        Dim s As String
        s = ActiveCell.Address


        datatoFind = "Potential False Detection"

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            With ws.Cells
                Set cell = .Find(What:=datatoFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress = cell.Address
                    Do

    If MsgBox("Delete this detection?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then

        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

    Else

       ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End If
                    Set cell = .FindNext(cell)
                    If cell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop Until cell.Address = FirstAddress
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I think I am not properly selecting the found cell as the active cell, but not sure how to correct this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that whenever you delete a row, you also delete the range that your `.FindNext` is referencing. Also, because you may delete rows, the `.Find` method may not reach the `FirstAddress` again. This way your code becomes an endless loop. I have made some changes to your code, and hopefully this works for you.

```
Sub deleteFalseManualInspection()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim datatoFind
    Dim FirstRow As Integer
    Dim RowsToDelete As Range

    datatoFind = "Potential False Detection"

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set RowsToDelete = Nothing
        ws.Select
        With ws.Cells
            Set cell = .Find(What:=datatoFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                FirstRow = cell.Row
                Do
                    cell.Select '<~~ Selects the cell so the user can see the row in question
                    Select Case MsgBox("Delete this detection in row?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion)
                    Case vbYes
                        'Adds the row to the range of rows to be deleted after the loop
                        If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                            Set RowsToDelete = cell
                        Else
                            Set RowsToDelete = Application.Union(RowsToDelete, cell)
                        End If
                    Case vbNo
                        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                    Case Else
                        Exit Sub
                    End Select

                    Set cell = .FindNext(after:=cell)
                Loop While Not cell Is Nothing And cell.Row > FirstRow

                'Deletes the rows selected for deletion
                If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then RowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Note that I have changed the code so that it won't delete any rows until you are out of the find-loop. This prevents removing the range that the `.FindNext` method needs to continue searching through the sheet.

**UPDATE:** The code is changed to use a `vbYesNoCancel`-MsgBox and a `Select Case`-statement to handle actions chosen by the user.

Comment: Wow, excellent! Your revisions are perfect. Beautiful coding. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Søren Holten Hansen, is there a way to exit the loop and make the deletions? Some sheets have hundreds of potential false detections, and the code right now allows only a break I tried using a vbyesnocancel and exit do on cancel, but got a compile "loop without do: error message.

Comment: @velvetmonster I have updated the code so the user is now able to cancel the loop.